# Tetration of Church numerals?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

I haven't seen any examples of [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) of [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), so I was trying to do it myself. Tetration is iterated exponention, for example: $2 \uparrow\uparrow 3={2^{2}}^{2}$. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions or references are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this would just follow a similar pattern to the slower growing functions. If we have typed Church numerals:

$$\mathsf{N} = ∀ r. r → (r → r) → r$$

Then successor can be defined as a base case as:

$$\mathsf{suc}\ n\ z\ s = s (n\ z\ s)$$

Addition is iterated successor:

$$m + n = n\ m\ \mathsf{suc}$$

Multiplication is iterated addition, and exponentiation is iterated multiplication:

$$m × n = n\ 0\ (λk. m + k)\\ m ^ n = n\ 1\ (λk. m × k)$$

And you can keep doing this:

$$m \uparrow\uparrow n = n\ 1\ (λ k . m ^ k) \\
m \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow n = n\ 1\ (λk. m \uparrow\uparrow k) \\
\vdots$$

One thing this relies on crucially, in a typed setting, is the ability to instantiate $r$ in the type of Church numerals with $\mathsf{N}$ itself (without types it's, of course, no problem either). If instead we are in a predicative setting, where quantifying over types can only be done by moving to a larger universe, then this process becomes more difficult, and which hyperoperations can be defined is related to how many universes there are. [See here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/is-church-pentation-implementable-in-agda) for some details.

Incidentally, in the first situation, it's possible to go beyond the hyperoperations and primitive recursion by instantiating $r$ to function types on $\mathsf{N}$. Essentially, we can iterate the process of iteration:

$$m \uparrow^k n = k\ (λ m\ n. m × n)\ (λ f\ m\ n. n\ 1\ (f\ m))$$

So, for $k = 0$ we get multiplication, for $k = 1$ we get exponentiation, for $k = 2$ we get tetration, and in general we get the $k$-th operation in [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).